# Secure Page Tab URL question - running the original version in a iframe inside a secure html file

Tags: facebook, ssl, tabs

I noticed a site that offers a free secure adaptor for page tab apps.
Looking at the source code, I saw that the adaptor was basically an iframe running my old insecure url inside a html file hosted on a secure server.

Is such a solution going to last for Facebook?
From what I read about SSL, this doesn't seem entirely legit and I wouldn't want to start using such a service and then discover that in a month or two Facebook will block these practices or that this sort of "secure" page will generate all sort of browser warnings

I don't really deal with Facebook data (except for signed_request and app_data), my app requires no permissions and no data from the user, so I won't need to interact with Facebook in my secure version, other than asking for the signed_request and possibly app data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't you still have a mixed content warning if the initial content is loaded over HTTPS and your original page is loaded over HTTP in an iframe?

Unless I'm missing something here, this solution is only going to solve the 'Facebook says i need a secure URL' problem, not 'Facebook says i need a secure URL so people can access my app over HTTPS without problems'

Comment: I know, that's exactly my problem. I don't need to simply trick Facebook, but also to be able to load the page without problems. From what I read, in order to have a https version of an app I will need to recreate that app in a secure folder, on the host. And this will be a bit tricky, since my "app" is more of an app generator. So this means I will have to create a new app twice each time, in different folders, and each modification I do will be done twice, yet again in different folders. I think this is overly complicated if it's true

Comment: I'm not sure what your server setup is, but with most setups you should be able to serve precisely the same content over HTTP or HTTPS from the same codebase and using the same URLs, with only the protocol identifier changing

Comment: So I would only have to change the urls to have everything starting with http to https if a secure browsing is detected? That would be great. I'm sorry if I seem noobish, but I can't seem to find an article to clear up this matter for me. I know what SSL is, I know how it is installed, I know why you should install it and so on, but I didn't manage to find a source of knowledge to clarify how I can convert a regular php script to its https version :|

Comment: If your server will respond to requests over HTTPS with a valid certificate, and it will serve the same content over HTTP as HTTPS, the only changes you should need to make to your codebase are to ensure that the URLs, image tags, etc you output as HTML are set to the correct (http or https) URL

Comment: Thank you for your help! Now I understand. I already installed SSL on my localhost and using what I just learned, I managed to get it working. Again, thank you, I am truly grateful, you don't know how stressed I was not being able to figure this out!